# What does "Sperit" means?

Tags: meaning

> I figgered about the Holy Sperit and the Jesus road. I figgered, ‘Why do we got to hang it on God or Jesus? Maybe,’ I figgered, ‘maybe it’s all men an’ all women we love; maybe that’s the Holy Sperit — the human sperit — the whole shebang. Maybe all men got one big soul ever’body’s a part of.’
>
> [*Grapes of Wrath,*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=hNisMz5W1DQC&pg=PT75&lpg=PT75&source=bl&ots=XB3AIpdAEU&sig=htdmPSf6e3uvmA57PxSNgV3bjtI&hl=en&sa=X&ei=3AcAVc3fCpKv7AbHiYHgAQ&ved=0CE0Q6AEwCQ#v=onepage&f=false) John Steinbeck, 1939

So what do *sperit* and *figger* mean?

Comment: Because it's *dialogue*, it's spelled like he said it (accented): I figured about (thought about) the Holy Sperit (Holy Spirit)...

Comment: I figgered about the Holy Sperit and the Jesus road. I figgered, ‘Why do we got to hang it on God or Jesus? Maybe,’ I figgered, ‘maybe it’s all men an’ all women we love; maybe that’s the Holy Sperit — the human sperit — the whole shebang. Maybe all men got one big soul ever’body’s a part of.’  so what does shebang and idears means?

Comment: Look up *the whole shebang* in a dictionary of slang, and idears = ideas.

Comment: Possibly related: [How to pronounce miracle?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/224890)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[figger](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/figger) is  a [pronunciation spelling](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pronunciation+spelling) of figure. [Sperit](https://www.wordnik.com/words/sperit) is an old spelling of spirit; I **figured** about the Holy **Spirit** and the Jesus road.

In this paragraph the character Jim Casy, a former preacher who lost his faith, is talking about his  his belief in the over-soul, a concept of man being a part of one soul, or the oversoul. [The oversoul](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Over-Soul) is coined by [Ralph Waldo Emerson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ralph_Waldo_Emerson) to mean " a spiritual essence or vital force in the universe in which all souls participate and that therefore transcends individual consciousness."(thefreedictionary.com).

Comment: @sumelic True it might be also a pronunciation spelling . You see I am not a native speaker though I lived and studied in beautiful America for five fruitful years.